# Calculate confidence intervals (%) from count data

Tags: confidence-interval

I am using two data sets to compare total population vs our dataset. E.g.

10% of population are in this age group (census data) vs. 15% of our observed population are in this age group (out dataset)

I would like to be able to show if this difference is statistically significant.

The data comes from raw numbers (discreet count data) for both and I am reasonably sure I should be using Poisson confidence intervals for discreet counts. That is fine for raw numbers, but when I am looking at %, I am not so sure how to proceed. As I am using total populations, it does not feel like any methods specifically specifying "sample size" are relevant to my case. (95% CI as an example below)

| Age Group | Census | LCI | UCI | Data | LCI | UCI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20-30 | 20 | 12.22 | 30.89 | 40 | 28.58 | 54.47 |
| All Others | 80 | 63.44 | 99.57 | 150 | 126.96 | 176.02 |
| Total | 100 |  |  | 190 |  |  |

(superfluous decimal points for now)

| Age Group | Census | LCI | UCI | Data | LCI | UCI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20-30 | 20% |  |  | 21.05% |  |  |
| All Others | 80% |  |  | 78.95% |  |  |

I am essentially looking to fill out the blank LCI/UCI for the % table above.

I *hope* I have not opened a whole can of statistical worms here and I hope the example given above with dummy data is enough to clarify what it is I am trying to do. I am also aware this may be an extremely simple question for those better-versed in statistics than I. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, "discreet" counts arrive in your mailbox in plain brown wrappers.  Count data are automatically *discrete* in the sense that that the natural numbers are a discrete subset of the real numbers.  As far as the substance of your question goes, a "census" means a *complete enumeration of a population.*  In what sense would those counts have confidence limits??

Comment: Do you want to test if the age distribution in your sample fits the age distribution of the population? A chi-squared goodness-of-fit test could be appropriate, but I'm not sure why you would group all ages together but 20-30. Of possible interest: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176617/how-to-test-a-sample-proportion-against-a-known-population-value

Comment: J-J-J - that could work, yes. Apologies, I am not sure how to reply directly to your comment. I will check the link. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesW there's no system to reply directly to a comment, just mention the person you're answering to by prepending a "@" to their username (this way, the person will get a notification). As for your question, you can edit it to add details, if you think it's useful (e.g. as to why you dichotomized the age distribution into "20-30" vs "all others", it may be useful to give you appropriate advice).